# Using pull-right in css stylesheet

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

New to bootstrap and playing around with using pull- instead of floats. eg

```
span class="item pull-right"><img src=css/graphics/jpeg/cart.jpg alt="Shopping Cart" height=20 width=19 />Items in Cart: <b class=simpleCart_quantity></b></span>
```

Just wondering if I can add this to a class selector in my stylesheet instead of manually adding it to every span or div. eg

```
.item {
? : pull-right?
padding: 0;
font-size: .8em }
```

Also if you can do the same thing to specify cols etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .pull-right has only `float: right` property. You can specify the same inside `.item` Make sure you create a custom class as it will effect all the items.

Comment: So are you saying I can choose either method and it has the same effect? Why use pull over float then?

Comment: They both are the same. `.pull-right` is a class for the float property. Got it? :)

Comment: yeah got it, thanks.